# unable to fetch the database's size

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm checking the size of my database(when I check the used database size I found it's in floating value) : I'm using this piece of code :

```
 Public class DBSize{

 private float dbSize;

    public float databaseSize(Float dbSize,String dataSize,String indexsize){
        String apps="apps";  // It's my DB name
        String query_data = "select table_schema,SUM(data_length+index_length)/1024/1024 AS total_mb,SUM(data_length)/1024/1024 AS data_mb,SUM(index_length)/1024/1024 AS index_mb,COUNT(*) AS tables,CURDATE() AS today FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema='"+apps+"' GROUP BY table_schema ORDER BY table_schema;";
        try {
            connection = getConnection();
            stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query_data);
            if(rs.next())      //as I'm selecting a particular database's information
            this.dbSize=rs.getFloat(2);
            this.dataSize=rs.getString(3);
            this.indexSize=rs.getString(4);

            System.out.println("DB Size : "+this.dbSize);           
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try {
                if(stmt != null)
                    stmt.close();
                if(connection != null)
                    connection.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return dbSize;

    }

public float getDbSize(){
        return dbSize;
    }
}
```

*`rs` is getting null value(don't know whether unable to fetch the value from database or not),even I have used String type the function but also getting the null value,*

Any inputs ...that where I'm going wrong :( :(

Comment: have you fired your query on your db first?

Comment: yes,..and also showing proper value

Comment: can you post the stack trace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep those three statements of assignment after `if` inside a block otherwise only first statement will get executed if the condidion `rs.next()`  evaluates to `true` and next 2 statements will always execute even if the condidion `rs.next()`  evaluates to `false`  which may cause some exception

```
if(rs.next()){     
   this.dbSize=rs.getFloat(2);
   this.dataSize=rs.getString(3);
   this.indexSize=rs.getString(4);
}
```

Comment: yeah may be but what I answered might help you

Comment: I'm not able to retrieve any value...so far :(

Comment: I don't know what exactly the issue is but I just wanted to point out what you would have required in order for your code/logic to work properly if everything else worked as expected.